# How to use hand-written cookbooks when using berkshelf in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, berkshelf

I'm using vagrant+chef. My chef cookbooks worked perfectly. Then I installed vagrant-berkshelf plugin and from that moment I could not use own cookbooks. Berkshelf overrides cookbooks directory and chef does not see my cookbooks when I use them. My config is like this:

```
config.berkshelf.enabled = true

config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
   chef.add_recipe "qbaka-frontend"
end
```

With this configuration chef works only with cookbooks specified in `Berksfile` but can't see my cookbooks in `cookbooks` directory.

How can I work simultaneously with my & Berkshelf's cookbooks?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin and Berkshelf in general is very cookbook-centric. Chef, however, is cookbook-repo centric. Installing the `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin encourages you to use the cookbook-centric approach, treating each cookbook like its own software project.

You need to add each of the cookbooks in your `cookbooks` directory to your Berksfile. There are a couple of approaches here:

1. If you only need one or two cookbooks, just add them using the [Berkshelf path location](http://berkshelf.com/#path_location):

   ```
   cookbook 'bacon', path: '~/cookbooks/bacon'
   ```
2. If you want *all* your cookbooks, you can leverage Ruby here. A little-known secret is that the `Berksfile` is executed as Ruby, so you can loop and be magical:

   ```
   Dir['/Users/sethvargo/cookbooks/**'].each do |path|
     cookbook File.basename(path), path: path
   end
   ```

   That will load each cookbook in that directory into your Berksfile (and thus Berkshelf)

Sources:

- I'm a core committer to the Berkshelf project
- I worked for Chef at the time of this post :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for this tool :). But why does it work so? I'd expect complete transparency from such kind of tools, like it is done in Maven.

Comment: @Daniil I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. Why is Berkshelf cookbook-centric?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better? Also I got a glob error using square braces
`Dir.glob('custom_cookbooks/**').each do |path| cookbook File.basename(path), path: path end`

Comment: From Berkshelf.com: "The Chef Solo provisioner’s cookbook_path attribute is hijacked when using the Vagrant Berkshelf plugin. Cookbooks resolved from your Berksfile will automatically be made available to your Vagrant virtual machine."

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the path to your cookbooks in your `Berksfile`.

```rb
 cookbook "artifact", path: "/Users/reset/code/artifact-cookbook"
```

See here: http://berkshelf.com/#path_location